# SPSS Statitics invalid variable name Python3

Tags: python, python-3.4, spss

I'm trying to generate some SPSS Statistics file (.sav) in python, and getting a traceback with my variable names..

I'm having the following traceback using *python's savReaderWriter*, and need your help..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\00231162\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.0.0.201605051159\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1530, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Users\00231162\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.0.0.201605051159\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 937, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\00231162\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.0.0.201605051159\pysrc\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\00231162\git\ParqueTecnologicoUFRGS\matrizbinaria.py", line 248, in <module>
    exporta_sav(resultados[0], resultados[1])       
  File "C:\Users\00231162\git\ParqueTecnologicoUFRGS\matrizbinaria.py", line 230, in exporta_sav
    with SavWriter(savFile2, cpcsN8Aux, varTypesNivel8, ioUtf8=True) as writer:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\savReaderWriter\savWriter.py", line 220, in __init__
    self.varNamesTypes = self.varNames, self.varTypes
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\savReaderWriter\header.py", line 196, in varNamesTypes
    raise SPSSIOError(msg, retcode)
error.SPSSIOError: b'A61F2/02' is an invalid variable name ['SPSS_NAME_BADCHAR: Invalid character or embedded blank']
```

my code:

```
def exporta_sav(matrizes, listas):
    #matrizes = [matriz_grupo, matriz_n8]
    #listas = [cpcs_grupo, patentes_grupo, cpcs_n8, patentes_n8]
    savFile1 = "matrizgrupo.sav"
    savFile2 = "matrizsubgrupo.sav"

    varTypesGrupo = {}
    varTypesNivel8 = {}

    stringpatente = 'PATENTE'

    #Cria lista auxiliar para fazer a matriz corretamente no formato .sav
    varTypesGrupo[stringpatente] = 7
    varTypesNivel8[stringpatente] = 7
    for i in range(len(listas[0])):
        varTypesGrupo[listas[0][i]] = 0
    for i in range(len(listas[2])):
        varTypesNivel8[listas[2][i]] = 0

    cpcsGrupoAux = [stringpatente]
    for i in range(len(listas[0])):
        cpcsGrupoAux.append(listas[0][i])
    cpcsN8Aux = [stringpatente]
    for i in range(len(listas[2])):
        cpcsN8Aux.append(listas[2][i])

    #Com as colunas definidas, vai criar listas auxiliares para cada linha 
    matrizGrupoAux = []
    matrizN8Aux = []
    if len(matrizes[0]) == len(listas[1]):
        for i in range(len(matrizes[0])):
            matrizGrupoAux.append([ listas[1][i] ])
            for j in range(len(matrizes[0][i])):
                matrizGrupoAux[i].append(matrizes[0][i][j])
        if len(matrizes[1]) == len(listas[3]):
            for i in range(len(matrizes[1])):
                matrizN8Aux.append([ listas[3][i] ])
                for j in range(len(matrizes[1][i])):
                    matrizN8Aux[i].append(matrizes[1][i][j])

            del listas
            del matrizes

            for i in range(len(matrizGrupoAux)):
                matrizGrupoAux[i][0] = bytes(matrizGrupoAux[i][0], "utf8")
            for i in range(len(matrizN8Aux)):
                matrizN8Aux[i][0] = bytes(matrizN8Aux[i][0], "utf8")

            #Escrever nos arquivos
            #try:
            with SavWriter(savFile1, cpcsGrupoAux, varTypesGrupo, ioUtf8=True) as writer:
                for patente in matrizGrupoAux:
                    writer.writerow(patente)
            with SavWriter(savFile2, cpcsN8Aux, varTypesNivel8, ioUtf8=True) as writer:
                for patente in matrizN8Aux:
                    writer.writerow(patente)
```

the first file it works well, the problem is the "/" on the second file variable names, and I need it to be in the names of the variables...
I've read the documentation, gone step by step on eclipse debugger and couldn't understand how to solve it..
anyone can help?

Comment: spss variable names can't have a "/" included, because otherwise the syntax interpreter could not decide if a/b is one variable or a divided by b. So I guess you need to replace the "/" by some other sign before exporting to sav. (Have a look at the python `replace` method for strings, for instance)

Comment: Note, in SPSS you can assign variable labels to variable names which in turn can include spaces and otherwise forbidden characters.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, I'll try to change it to _, i think that will work